# Select check box from check box list xsl umbraco

Tags: xslt, checkbox, umbraco

I have a check box list with two check boxes. I want to output a link when either of them are checked. Both check boxes can be checked at the same time, or just one checked, or none at all.

I have a a variable named value where I am getting the dataType 2084 which is the check box list.

How can I target an individual check box within the list when it is checked. There preValues are 99 and 101.

Anyone who can help I am very much thankful!

Here is my attempt below.

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:param name="parentNode" select="/macro/parentNode"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/OperationsMap[@id=$parentNode]/MarkerItem">

        <xsl:variable name="value" select="umbraco.library:GetPreValues('2084')"/>


        <div class="popup-box">

          <xsl:if test="$value/preValue[@alias='99'] = '1'">  
            <div class="colorbox-link-container">  
               <a href="#" class="colorboxLink">View current gallery</a>
             </div>     
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="$value/preValue[@alias='101'] = '1'">
              <div class="colorbox-link-container">
                <a href="#" class="colorboxLink">View historical project progress</a>
              </div>   
            </xsl:if>
        </div>

 </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetPreValues` returns a data set for the umbraco raw data type, not the status if they're checked or not on any particular content node.

**Assumptions (as not specified in question):**

Your data type is going to look something like the following:

```
<preValues>
    <preValue id="99">Red</preValue>
    <preValue id="100">Green</preValue>
    <preValue id="101">Blue</preValue>
</preValues>
```

Not knowing the property alias you gave the checkbox list when adding the data type to the document type, I'm just going to use the following

```
MarkerItem/colours
```

**Code:**

This code was written on the fly, so haven't had time to test it.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/OperationsMap[@id=$parentNode]/MarkerItem">

    <div class="popup-box">

        <!-- get the colours checked on MarkerItem -->
        <xsl:variable name="colours" select="./colours"/>
        <xsl:variable name="coloursValues" select="umbraco.library:Split($colours, ',')" />

        <!-- cycle through each of the checked colours -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$coloursValues/value">

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'Red'">
                    <div class="colorbox-link-container">  
                        <a href="#" class="colorboxLink">View current gallery</a>
                    </div>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test=". = 'Blue'">
                    <div class="colorbox-link-container">
                        <a href="#" class="colorboxLink">View historical project progress</a>
                    </div>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </div>
```

Hopefully, that does the trick for you. Obviously, update any reference to colours and their value to what is specific to you.

Comment: This works fine, thank you so much. Selecting a single checked 'true/false' box is simple, but this is definitely trickier! again, thanks a bunch!